# Continued fraction, serie and the Ramanujan Easiest Theorem

Tags: math, octave, scientific-computing

Based on [this](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/ramanujan/ramanujan_whittier_web.pdf) interesting presentation on the web, I tried to prove by programming that

[image]

I used Octave but I faced a large error in the computation. Where is my mistake?

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC0wB.gif)

Here is the code:

```
function [ref, reali, err] = rama(n)
  a(1) = 1;
  for i=2:n
    a(i) = (2*i+1)*a(i-1);
  endfor
  b = 1./a;
  S = sum(b);

  p = '1';
  for k = n:-1:1
    s = int2str(k);
    p = ['1+' s '/( ' p ' )'];
  endfor
  P = str2num(p);
  P ^=(-1);

  ref = S + P;
  reali = sqrt(pi*exp(1)*0.5);
  err = abs(reali - ref);
endfunction
```

Comment: `S` should be about 1.41069 (putting the second red equation into Wolfram Alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28e%29++%2A+integral+from+0+to+1+exp%28-t%5E2%2F2%29+dt). Does that converge correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making a rather unwarranted assumption when it comes to your recursive fraction's base case, that at the point where you decide to stop, the last "1 + recurse" step is equal to "1 + 0" (and additionally, that chopping that last recursion part does not affect your solution by much).

In fact, the chopped out bit turns out (by trial and error) to be "1 + π" rather than "1 + 0", and it turns out that chopping it out propagates a big error all the way back up, affecting the outcome by a lot.

Modifying the base case in your calculation to account for the missing π makes your approximation a lot more accurate.

```
  for k = n:-1:2
    s = int2str(k);
    p = ['1+' s '/( ' p ' )'];
  endfor
  p = ['1+1/( ' p ' + ' num2str(pi) ' )'];
```

```
octave:1> [ ref, reali, err ] = rama(5)
ref = 2.0613
reali = 2.0664
err = 5.0994e-03
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried more and realized that 3.52 is more exact than pi. With this value, the error becomes 0.00027361

Comment: @Milo interesting. I remembered reading in the past that there are [several formulations of pi as a continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Continued_fractions). I just took it for granted that this would almost surely simply turn out to be one of them! :p